# Retrieve all instances of recurring event via CSOM

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-online

I need to get all the instances of a recurring calendar event in Sharepoint 2013 online via CSOM. I read that it can't be done, that I need to do it via REST API directly.

My question:

1) Is it possible to get the items from a View instead of from a List, because the calendar comes with a default view where I can see all instances of the recurring event

2) I have an example of retrieveing data via REST un C# that's working fine, but I can't seem to add a Caml Query to it (in C#)
here's my non-working code:

```
HttpWebRequest itemRequest =
                (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/Items");
            itemRequest.Method = "POST";
            itemRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
            itemRequest.ContentType = "application/atom+xml;type=entry";
            itemRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(itemRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(@"{ 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 'ViewXml': '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'/><Value Type='Text'>little test</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>' } }");
            }

            HttpWebResponse itemResponse = (HttpWebResponse)itemRequest.GetResponse();
```

I get 500 Internal server error

Any thoughts??
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Vadim Gremyachev, your post got me on track.

I had 3 problems, the first one was calling "Items" instead of "getItems", and the second one was using "application/atom+xml;type=entry" as a ContentType (just as Vadim stated).

The third and last problem, was using simple quotes all over the query. Inside the ViewXml, I used scaped double quotes so they were not confused with the one closing the ViewXml element.

So, the working code ended up being like this:

```
byte[] data = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("{ 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 'ViewXml': '<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">little test</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>' } }");

        HttpWebRequest itemRequest =
            (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(sharepointUrl.ToString() + "/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/getitems");
        itemRequest.Method = "POST";
        itemRequest.ContentType = "application/json; odata=verbose";
        itemRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
        itemRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        itemRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
        Stream myStream = itemRequest.GetRequestStream();
        myStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        myStream.Close();         

        HttpWebResponse itemResponse = (HttpWebResponse)itemRequest.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to utilize [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect REST SharePoint RESTfull web service requests.

In your case the endpoint is not correct. Since you need to request list items via CAML query, replace endpoint url from:

```
/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/Items
```

to this one:

```
/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/getitems
```

Secondly, `application/atom+xml;type=entry` HTTP `Content-Type` header is not supported in POST requests (see the list of supported MIME types below). So, replace the lines:

```
itemRequest.Accept = "application/atom+xml";
itemRequest.ContentType = "application/atom+xml;type=entry";
```

for example, with these ones:

```
itemRequest.Accept = "application/json";
itemRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
```

That's it.

### The list of supported MIME types

- application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true
- application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=false
- application/json;odata=minimalmetadata
- application/json;odata=fullmetadata;streaming=true
- application/json;odata=fullmetadata;streaming=false
- application/json;odata=fullmetadata
- application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=true
- application/json;odata=nometadata;streaming=false
- application/json;odata=nometadata
- application/json;streaming=true
- application/json;streaming=false
- application/json;odata=verbose
- application/json

---

You could also utilize the following class for performing REST requests:

```
public class SPRestExecutor
{

    public SPRestExecutor(Uri webUri,string accessToken)
    {
        WebUri = webUri;
        AccessToken = accessToken;
    }



    public JObject ExecuteJsonWithDigest(string endpointUrl, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> headers, JObject payload)
    {
        var formDigestValue = RequestFormDigest();
        var finalHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        if (headers != null)
        {
            foreach (var key in headers.Keys)
            {
                finalHeaders.Add(key, headers[key]);
            }
        }
        finalHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", formDigestValue);

        var result = ExecuteJson(endpointUrl, method, finalHeaders, payload);
        return result;
    }


    public JObject ExecuteJson(string endpointUrl, HttpMethod method, IDictionary<string, string> headers, JObject payload)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WebUri.ToString() + endpointUrl);
        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + AccessToken);
        request.Method = method.Method;
        request.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        request.ContentType = "application/json;odata=verbose";
        if (payload != null)
        {
            using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                writer.Write(payload);
                writer.Flush();
            }
        }
        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using(var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return JObject.Parse(result);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Request Form Digest
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected string RequestFormDigest()
    {
        var result = ExecuteJson("/_api/contextinfo", HttpMethod.Post, null, null);
        return result["d"]["GetContextWebInformation"]["FormDigestValue"].ToString();
    }


    public string AccessToken { get; private set; }


    public Uri WebUri { get; private set; }
}
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/11de39a33cbdbecdbf94)

Usage

```
var client = new SPRestExecutor(webUri,accessToken);
var payload = JObject.Parse(@"{ 'query' : {'__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 'ViewXml': '<View><Query/></View>' } }");
var data = client.ExecuteJson("/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/getitems", HttpMethod.Post, null, payload);
```